# Apply Data to SpatialLines Object

Tags: r, attributes, spatial, lines

I've read Lines from different gpx files to R and combined them into one SpatialLines object. Now I would like to apply the gpx-names (chr-vector "names") as attributes to the spatial dataset "tracksSL" but I'm stuck here..

```
library(sp)
library(gdal)

setwd("D:/WEB/gardaweb")

files <- dir(pattern="*.gpx$", recursive = T, include.dirs = T)

spl <- lapply(files, function(x) {readOGR(x,"tracks")@lines[[1]]} )

lines <- lapply( spl , function(x) `@`(x , "Lines"))
tracks <- Lines(unlist(lines), ID = "Tracks")
tracksSL <- SpatialLines(list(tracks))

names <- basename(files)

str(tracksSL)
>> 
Formal class 'SpatialLines' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
  ..@ lines      :List of 1
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Lines:List of 15
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:2322, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:2961, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:2201, 1:2] 10.7 10.7 10.7 10.7 10.7 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:3329, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:2976, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:3333, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:2484, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:746, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:3373, 1:2] 11 11 11 11 11 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:2286, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:1612, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:1315, 1:2] 10.7 10.7 10.7 10.7 10.7 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:4342, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:4168, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:2366, 1:2] 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 10.9 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ ID   : chr "Tracks"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 10.6 45.7 11.1 46
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA

str(names)
>> 
chr [1:15] "601er RifugiGraziani.gpx" "Bocca dei Fortini.gpx" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
    library(sp)
    library(gdal) 
    library(plotKML)

    setwd("D:/WEB/gardaweb")

    files <- dir(pattern="*.gpx$", recursive = T, include.dirs = T)

    spl <- lapply(files, function(x) {readOGR(x, "tracks")@lines[[1]]} )
    str(spl)

    for(i in 1:length(spl)) {slot(spl[[i]], "ID") <- as.character(i)}
    tracksSL <- SpatialLines(spl, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

    summary(tracksSL)
    plot(tracksSL)

    df <- data.frame(names = basename(files), row.names = sapply(slot(tracksSL, "lines"), function(x) slot(x, "ID")))
    tracksSLDF <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(tracksSL, data = df)

    plotKML(tracksSLDF, "tracks_collection")
```